# Prove inequality $\frac{a+1}{b^2+1}+\frac{b+1}{c^2+1}+\frac{c+1}{a^2+1}\ge3$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=3$. Prove that
> $$\frac{a+1}{b^2+1}+\frac{b+1}{c^2+1}+\frac{c+1}{a^2+1}\ge3$$

#### My work so far:

I use AM-GM:
$$\frac{a+1}{b^2+1}=\frac{a}{b^2+1}+\frac{1}{b^2+1}=$$
$$=a-\frac{ab^2}{b^2+1}+1-\frac{b^2}{b^2+1}\ge a+1-\frac{ab^2}{2b}-\frac{b^2}{2b}=$$
$$=a+1-\frac{ab}{2}-\frac{b}{2}$$
Then
$$\frac{a+1}{b^2+1}+\frac{b+1}{c^2+1}+\frac{c+1}{a^2+1}\ge a+1-\frac{ab}{2}-\frac{b}{2}+b+1-\frac{bc}{2}-\frac{c}{2}+c+1-\frac{ca}{2}-\frac{a}{2}=$$
$$=3+\frac{a+b+c}{2}-\frac{ab+bc+ca}{2}=\frac92-\frac{ab+bc+ca}{2}$$
*I need help here*

Comment: I can't believe how you did all the hard work but does not know $\sum ab\le\sum a^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there :).

Inequality $$(a+b+c)^2\geq 3(ab+bc+ac)$$ holds, since it is equivalent with $$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\geq 0.$$ Therefore, $$\frac92-\frac{ab+bc+ca}{2}\geq \frac92-\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{6}=3$$